# Strange behaviour of BooleanToVisibilityConverter using with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

In my WPF application I use Caliburn.Micro (2.0.1). In App.xaml I declare BooleanToVisibilityConverter

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
```

Now when I want use in one of my view this converter  I wrote something like that

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Visibility="{Binding visibility,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis} }"/>
```

Everything works great but now I must use this converter in my MainVeiew. This View is my primary view. When application starts it's throw exception

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
```

It is verry strange for me because if I write in my View

```
<Window.Resources>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis2" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and use BoolToVis2 instead of BoolToVis everything  works fine. It i no big deal but I dont understand this behaviour.

Sample code of applcation:

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
         >
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

AppBootstrapper

```
public class AppBootstrapper:BootstrapperBase
{
    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
        DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : Screen
{
    bool _visibility;


    public bool Visibility
    {
        get { return _visibility; }
        set
        {
            _visibility = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Visibility");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
        Visibility = false;
    }
}
```

MainView

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainView" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Test" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: It should've worked, so the problem is proably somewhere else. Try to rperoduce this in a nimimal app and if it still fails, post that code.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility property for any UIElement gets values from Visibility enumerator.
instead of using boolean use Visible,Hidden or Collapsed.